# XQuery in eXist-db get last item of each subject in a record and compare it - how do I use group-by here?

Tags: group-by, xquery, grouping, exist-db, distinct-values

(This Question has been edited.)

Dear Community,

I am not very experienced in XQuery and currently facing the following problem while working with CDISC xml documents. I have already spend quite a while on this specific Query and I know I'll be thrilled when I finally get it right.

I am using `xquery version "3.0";`

I have several records in one document that look like this.

```
<ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="DM" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="1">
            <ItemData ItemOID="DM.USUBJID" Value="01-701-1015"/>
            <ItemData ItemOID="DM.RFXSTDTC" Value="2014-01-02"/>
  </ItemGroupData>
<ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="DM" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="2">
            <ItemData ItemOID="DM.USUBJID" Value="01-701-1023"/>
            <ItemData ItemOID="DM.RFXSTDTC" Value="2014-02-02"/>
  </ItemGroupData>
```

and another document with several records like this:

```
    <ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="EX" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="1" >
            <ItemData ItemOID="EX.USUBJID" Value="01-701-1015"/>
            <ItemData ItemOID="EX.EXSEQ" Value="1"/>
            <ItemData ItemOID="EX.EXSTDTC" Value="2014-06-19"/>
            <ItemData ItemOID="EX.EXENDTC" Value="2014-06-21"/>
    </ItemGroupData>
    <ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="EX" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="2" >
            <ItemData ItemOID="EX.USUBJID" Value="01-701-1015"/>
            <ItemData ItemOID="EX.EXSEQ" Value="2"/>
            <ItemData ItemOID="EX.EXSTDTC" Value="2014-06-19"/>
            <ItemData ItemOID="EX.EXENDTC" Value="2014-06-27"/>
    </ItemGroupData>
    <ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="EX" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="3" >
            <ItemData ItemOID="EX.USUBJID" Value="01-701-1015"/>
            <ItemData ItemOID="EX.EXSEQ" Value="3"/>
            <ItemData ItemOID="EX.EXSTDTC" Value="2014-06-19"/>
            <ItemData ItemOID="EX.EXENDTC" Value="2014-07-02"/>
    </ItemGroupData>
   <ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="EX" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="4" >
            <ItemData ItemOID="EX.USUBJID" Value="01-701-1023"/>
            <ItemData ItemOID="EX.EXSEQ" Value="1"/>
            <ItemData ItemOID="EX.EXSTDTC" Value="2014-06-19"/>
            <ItemData ItemOID="EX.EXENDTC" Value="2014-07-02"/>
    </ItemGroupData>
   <ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="EX" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="5" >
            <ItemData ItemOID="EX.USUBJID" Value="01-701-1023"/>
            <ItemData ItemOID="EX.EXSEQ" Value="2"/>
            <ItemData ItemOID="EX.EXSTDTC" Value="2014-06-19"/>
            <ItemData ItemOID="EX.EXENDTC" Value=""/>
    </ItemGroupData>
```

I want to check, if the last `EXSTDTC` (that with the `max(EXSEQ)` of the `EX` dataset equals the corresponding (with the same `USUBJID` - the unique `ID`) `RFXSTDTC`.

And suppose, `EXENDTC` is `null`, then `RFXSTDTC` should equal the last `EXSTDTC` (but if I only knew how to check only `EXENDTC` I could probably solve that one on my own)

I still just don’t quite know how to do actually write that and I would be very happy if someone of you could please show me how to do that.

Again, I hope that I was precise enough and that you can help me, thank you in advance!

Responding to the first comment: Thank you very much for your help! You are right, distinct-values are quite time-consuming since my dataset comprises about 300 records (and actually, I am only testing on the first 10 - takes already 6 seconds). To group by seems to be the right approach!

update(12/05/2015)

I tried to solve my problem in the following way but I do not get the value of exendtcvalue in my return expression. To be generic, I use $oids that I retrieved from another metadata xml document.

```
for $record in doc($dmdatasetlocation)//odm:ItemGroupData[@data:ItemGroupDataSeq < 5][odm:ItemData[@ItemOID=$usubjidoid]]
let $recnum := $record/@data:ItemGroupDataSeq
let $dmusubjidvalue := $record/odm:ItemData[@ItemOID=$usubjidoid]/@Value
let $rfxendtcvalue := $record/odm:ItemData[@ItemOID=$rfxendtcoid]/@Value
let $exendtcvalue := (
    for $a in doc($exdatasetlocation)//odm:ItemGroupData[odm:ItemData[@ItemOID=$exusubjidoid and @Value=$dmusubjidvalue]]
    let $maxseqvalue := functx:max-string(doc($exdatasetlocation)//ItemGroupData[odm:ItemData[@IItemOID=$exusubjidoid and @Value=$dmusubjidvalue]][odm:ItemData[@ItemOID=$exseqoid]]/@Value)
    where $a = doc($exdatasetlocation)//odm:ItemGroupData[odm:ItemData[@ItemOID=$exusubjidoid and @Value=$dmusubjidvalue]][odm:ItemData[@ItemOID=$exseqoid and @Value=$maxseqvalue]][odm:ItemData[@ItemOID=$exendtcoid]]/@Value
    return $a
)   


 where  not($exendtcvalue=$rfxendtcvalue)

 (: ((functx:if-empty($exendtcvalue, 0)) and :)
 (:     or (functx:if-empty($exendtcvalue, 0) and ($rfxendtcvalue=$exstdtcvalue)) :)

return <warning rule="SPC_DM_RFXENDTC_01" rulelastupdate="2015-02-11" recordnumber="{data($recnum)}">RFXENDTC, value={data($rfxendtcvalue)} in dataset {data($dmdatasetname)} is not an allowed value, it should be the same as the last EX.EXENDTC value ={data($exendtcvalue)} </warning>
```

Thank you for your help!
Christiane

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify whether your XQuery processor supports 3.0 or only 1.0 - in 3.0 you can use `group by`, which would be particularly handy here. However, it's possible to achieve the same result in either version using `distinct-values`:

```
let $subject-ids := fn:distinct-values(//ItemGroupData/ItemData[@ItemOID="subject_ID"]/@Value)
for $id in $subject-ids
let $grouped := //ItemGroupData[ItemData[@ItemOID="subject_ID" and @Value=$id]]
let $max := fn:max($grouped/ItemData[@ItemOID="Sequence"]/@Value)
return $grouped[ItemData[@ItemOID="Sequence" and @Value=$max]]
```

For a large data set, `distinct-values` does not perform well. Depending on your XQuery processor, there may implementation specific optimizations you could use to improve performance, or in many cases that's simply using `group by`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried to specify the question because I could not come up with a solution so far and I know, distinct-values are (as you said) not performing well on (my) large dataset.

Comment: @ChristianePrutsch What XQuery processor are you using? There may be indexes available or that are configurable to facilitate this type of query.

Comment: I am using Xquey Version 3.0 (eXist). I tried to improve my question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ChristianePrutsch In that case you can use `group by`, which eXist says is far more optimized than `distinct-values`.

Comment: thank you! I tried to solve it with group by but I did not work and I am not enough experienced. I tried it differently - but I don't get the value of my exendtcvalue.. can you help me again?

Comment: @ChristianePrutsch Your question has changed so much, it might be best to ask another one. Simplify it if possible and be sure to tag it with `exist-db` so eXist experts will see it.